# Icon Size Change

Tags: icons

I'm new to Linux, about 2 weeks. I booted up this morning, and all my icons and associated fonts are miniscule, in all my programs. The layout for Thunderbird is so small that I can hardly read the e-mail list. Similarly the icons etc in Firefox, etc. are really small.

When I do open up emails, or open a web page on Firefox, the font sizes are fine. I have tinkered with some settings, but nothing seems to work on the default settings. So, two questions:

1. What has happened overnight, to change all my icon sizes?
2. How do I fix it?

Here is the screenshot, but your suggestion of Ubuntu Tweak was a really good one, and seems to have fixed the problem Thank You!

Let's try this: ![Thunderbired Screen Shot][1]
file:///home/pat/Desktop/Screenshot%20from%202014-05-09%2011:43:47.png

It says that I need a "reputation 10" to post images, sorry!

Comment: what Ubuntu release are you running?

Comment: Can you show some screen shot? Toni

Comment: Here is a screenshot of my Thunderbird Inbox Folder_ file:///home/pat/Desktop/Screenshot%20from%202014-05-09%2011:43:47.png

Answer (score 0):

First answer: I don't know.

Second answer: go to system preferences > appearance and it should show beneath your wallpapers a slider for your icon size. If you don't see it, log out and click the ubuntu icon and select ubuntu. Your system should support unity 3d.

Another thing you can do is download/install an application like [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Lemmeask. I did the slider thing which changed the icons on my desktop, but not in any programs that I'm running. I think I posted a screenshot in a reply to Toni Ridwan's comment. Not sure if you'll be able to see it,....but just in case, here it is,...I hope: file:///home/pat/Desktop/Screenshot%20from%202014-05-09%2011:43:47.png

Comment: Nope, don't see it. Says no existing webpage. Can you upload it or no?

Comment: I saved the screenshot, copied it, then pasted it in the comments. Is there another method to post it here

Comment: Thanks Lemmeask, I just downloaded Ubuntu Tweak, and did a bit of tweaking with defaults fonts, and seems to have worked pretty well.

Comment: It isn't in your comment. Edit your question and and press Ctrl+G and upload your image.